# Is there a tikz style for putting math in all nodes?

Tags: math-mode, tikz-pgf

I'm finally trying out TikZ and am already infected with its programmatic philosophy.  I would like to be able to do something like

```
every node/.style = {math mode}
```

(which is wrong) so that I can omit the $...$ inside the text of my nodes.  This is not just for convenience; without it, the equally appealing setting

```
every node/.style = {font=\scriptstyle}
```

is wrong (the `\scriptstyle` goes outside the math mode), and I can certainly find a use for math nodes set in small text.  I know I can get this, sort of, with the `matrix` library (using a `matrix of math nodes`), but I am resisting using matrices.  I really like the idea of relational positioning and I hate all the empty &'s that complex use of matrices always requires.

So, is this possible?  How does `matrix of math nodes` achieve its effect?

Comment: Please close this.  Or at least, could an admin make it CW?  I do not deserve any reputation for asking it.

Comment: @Ryan: You definitely deserve reputation from this!  I was wondering how to do something similar (with fixed text) the other day, and I wouldn't have known the answer without this question (I didn't think of `matrix of math nodes`).  Just because it's easy to answer, doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: Another day, another thing learned about TikZ.

Comment: @Ryan: Great question!

Comment: @Ryan: Completely agree with the comments other than yours!  Just because you figured out the answer shortly after posting doesn't mean that anyone else would have done so.

Comment: I may have figured out the answer to the question as asked, but it turns out that `font = \scriptstyle` still doesn't work (complains about missing $).  You can write `execute at begin node = \scriptstyle`, of course, but it lacks that certain something.

Comment: Regarding the order of font and begin node, I'd like to link this question to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48918/86

Comment: Okay, I have to admit that after two years, the popular appeal of this question has proven to me that it is *not* stupid.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the matrix library file, at `texmf/tex/generic/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex` (what you get with `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}`, we can find the definition of `matrix of math nodes` (in my version, it's on lines 74–81):

```
% Same as a matrix of nodes, but switch on math mode in each cell
\tikzstyle{matrix of math nodes}=[%
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={%
   execute at begin node=$,%
   execute at end node=$%
  }%
]
```

So you can just use `execute at begin node`/`execute at end node`.  Interestingly, these keys don't seem to be documented, at least in my version of the manual.  If you want a `math mode` style, then you can write `\tikzset{math mode/.style = {execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$}}`; then just including `math mode` in your options list will do what you want (no need for `every node/.style`, since the option implicitly affects all nodes).

These options can do more than just math, too; consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$]
      \node at (-1.5,-0.375) {\mathfrak{A} \models \varphi_i} ;
      \node at (-1.5,-0.875) {0 \in \mathbb{N}} ;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[ color                 = blue
                 , execute at begin node = $\displaystyle
                 , execute at end node   = $]
      \node at (+1.5, 0.00) {\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 2} ;
      \node at (+1.5,-1.25) {n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i} ;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}
      [ execute at begin node=\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Important notice:} },
      , execute at end node={{} --- \textit{The Management}} ]
      \node at (0,-2.5) {\TeX{} is very powerful.} ;
      \node at (0,-3.0) {Ti\textit{k}Z is a useful graphics language.} ;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following picture:

[image: Sample use of the above options.]

The option, as we can see, can be used for more than just `$...$`; it works while specifying other options, or with arbitrary text.  (Note that, if specifying arbitrary text, be careful with your leading/trailing spaces; it can be tough to get them to appear.)  It doesn't work with `\[...\]` (probably because that enters vmode), but `$\displaystyle...$` works fine.

---

**Edit:** As Ryan points out, it's worth clarifying that the TeX which is an argument to `font` is inserted *before* the TeX which is an argument to `execute at begin node`, which is relevant in that using the above style to get math nodes, `font=\scriptstyle` doesn't work, since it goes outside the `$...$`.  (You need `execute at begin node=$\scriptstyle, execute at end node=$`.)

Comment: It is definitely not documented, though the similar style `execute at begin cell` (for matrices) is.  Not that I would have thought to look there for math mode.

Comment: Since, as you say, your answer says "the same thing" as mine, you won't object if I accept it.

Comment: This is not a criticism of your answer, but I feel like I should record the unfortunate fact that one *still* cannot use `font = \scriptstyle` even with this method.  This is because tikz installs the font before the `at begin node` material (as would make sense, if indeed this material were text to prefix the node and not formatting code).  One must use `execute at begin node = \scriptstyle` after creating a "math node" in the above manner.

Comment: @Ryan: Good point, I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

I probably shouldn't have asked this in the first place, as the most cursory glance into tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex answers it instantly.  For posterity (since it is not obvious to me, as a beginner) I record the answer to my second question.

```
\tikzstyle{matrix of math nodes}=[%
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={%
   execute at begin node=$,%
   execute at end node=$%
  }%
]
```

So, to answer my first question, one should just use `execute at begin node` and `execute at end node` to wrap the text in $'s.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your answer—mine pretty much says the same thing :-)