# How to dynamically name and store macros/variables in \foreach in TikZ for later use?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am generating a figure in TikZ using the `\foreach` command, dynamically setting the node values using a macro (adapted from this question: [TikZ: Using Loop to Draw Grid of Nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/tikz-using-loop-to-draw-grid-of-nodes)).

Now, I want to reuse the nodes' labels at a later point in my document, but they don't seem to be stored (see [Is it possible to refer to node label and reuse it for labeling other nodes in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52270/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-node-label-and-reuse-it-for-labeling-other-nodes-in-t)). I thus need to somehow use macros to store the labels.

Is it somehow possible to dynamically generate names for macros/variable (e.g. `\label1`, `\label2`, ..., `\labelN`), and then use `\pgftruncatemacro{\myLabel}{...}` to store a value in those?

Here is my code example (where I am of course not doing the above yet). I have indicate the relevant part. I essentially want to get variables indexed by `\x` and `\y` so that I can use them later as “`\label\x\y`”:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mainstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!40,minimum size=20}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \def\xmin{1}
  \def\xmax{4}
  \def\ymin{1}
  \def\ymax{5}
  \def\lattconst{3.0}

  \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}
    \foreach \y in {\ymin,...,\ymax}
    {
      %%%
      % This should be a dynamic, e.g. “\{label\x\y}”
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - \xmax *  \y + \xmax * \ymax}
      %%%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{\lattconst*\x}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ypos}{\lattconst*\y}
      \node [mainstyle] (\x\y) at (\xpos,\ypos) {\label};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For TeX it's very nontrivial and also not so smart to use numbers in macro names. In fact practically you can say, you can't use numbers in macro names (unless you pull off some strange tricks). Use Tikz arrays instead

Comment: I just found a related question, where one answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38624/6993) suggests this: `\expandafter\let\expandafter\thiscnt\csname cnt\i\endcsname`. Do you think it's a bad idea to use this code?

Comment: @mSSM It is not bad to use macros with numbers. It can be tremendously useful to generate macro names dynamically with a counter. Caveat: you should be aware that you will need to surround that macro with `\csname ...\endcsname` everytime you need to expand it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to store your `\label` in relation with `\x` and `\y` via the two macros `\storelabel` and `\getlabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\storelabel[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname label#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\getlabel[1]{\csname label#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{mainstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!40,minimum size=20}}
  \def\xmin{1}
  \def\xmax{4}
  \def\ymin{1}
  \def\ymax{5}
  \def\lattconst{3.0}
  \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}
    \foreach \y in {\ymin,...,\ymax}
    {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - \xmax *  \y + \xmax * \ymax}
      \storelabel{\x-\y}{\label}
      %%%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{\lattconst*\x}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ypos}{\lattconst*\y}
      \node [mainstyle] (\x-\y) at (\xpos,\ypos) {\label};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

Label of 3-4 is \getlabel{3-4}.

Label of 1-1 is \getlabel{1-1}.

Label of 4-5 is \getlabel{4-5}.

\end{document}
```