# Coloring a node after its creation

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to fill a node with a specific color, but not with the usual `[fill=blue]` way. The reason is, that I am creating many many nodes and I want to fill some random nodes with a different color from the others, so the coloring can not be embedded in the creation process. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!20,minimum size=20}]


  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,1}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south); 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (10+1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,2}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south); 



  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Lets say we want to fill with blue color the top leftmost node and the bottom rightmost node.

Comment: why can't you colour randomly as you create? in any case your question would be much clearer (and much easier to test possible answers) if you provided a sample document.

Comment: First idea: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please see the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!20,minimum size=20},
bluestyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=blue!20,minimum size=20},
]


  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
\ifnum\x=\ifnum\y=2 0\else-1\fi
       \node [bluestyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};
\else
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};
\fi
       } 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,1}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south); 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (10+1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,2}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south); 



  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
\ifnum\x=\ifnum\y=0 5\else-1\fi
       \node [bluestyle]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};
\else
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};
\fi

} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I group in your if statement more coordinates? (Like not only 2 0 but also 1 1)? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Paramar you can use any tex tests, there are packages that let you use more sensible infix logical operators or you could just `\ifnum\x=\ifnum\y=0 5\else-1\fi
       \node [bluestyle]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};
\else\ifnum\x=\ifnum\y=1 1\else-1\fi
       \node [bluestyle]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};\else
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};
\fi\fi`

Answer (score 10):

In your question you said that you want to fill random nodes. If you want a realy random choice you can do the following random `darkstyle` style :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
  % ----- the static part of the style
  darkstyle/.style={
    circle,minimum size=20,draw
  },
  % ----- the random part of the style
  darkstyle/.append code = {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\randcolor{{"red!50","blue!35"}[int(2*random())]}
    \pgfkeysalso{fill=\randcolor}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,1}
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south);

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (10+1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,2}
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south);

  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT : And if you don't realy want a random choice, you can prescribe some nodes to be with different color like this :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
  % ----- the static part of the style
  darkstyle/.style={
    circle,minimum size=20,draw, fill = blue!35
  },
  % ----- the prescribed part pf the style
  mycolor/.style = {fill=red!35},
  mycolorA12/.style = {mycolor},
  mycolorA20/.style = {mycolor},
  mycolorB11/.style = {mycolor},
  mycolorC54/.style = {mycolor},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle,mycolorA\x\y/.try]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,1}
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south);

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle,mycolorB\x\y/.try]  (\x\y) at (10+1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,2}
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (20.south) -- (00.south);

  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle,mycolorC\x\y/.try]  (\x\y) at (3+1.5*\x,-10+1.5*\y) {};}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi)  ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, I upvoted it. I do not really need a real random choice, but I learned something from your code I did not know in the past. Thank you

Comment: Ok. If "random nodes" doesn't meen random, I came to edit another not so random styling ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, consider a simpler example (one that applies to the original example directly) so that the answer can actually be understood and adapted by people from the future:

- `(node1)` and `(node2)` are respectively drawn as a circle and a rectangle, and
- we seek to re-color the former as blue.

I don't know if re-coloring is possible, but if you haven't already drawn something else over `(node1)`, then drawing a blue-colored node right on top of `(node1)` could work for you:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!20,minimum size=20}]

    \node [darkstyle] (node1) at (2,1) {};
    \node [darkstyle, rectangle] (node2) at (4,2) {};

    % What to write here to change the color of (node1) to blue?
    % A workaround:
    \node [darkstyle, fill=blue!30] at (node1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: nodes without text]

---

If your old node also had some text in it, then that also needs to be the label of the overlaid node.  Those can either be hard-coded, or stored in a macro and recalled.  Let's do it with `(node2)` this time:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Thanks to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175707/69346
\newcommand\storelabel[2]{\expandafter\xdef\csname label#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\getlabel[1]{\csname label#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!20,minimum size=20}]

    \node [darkstyle] (node1) at (2,1) {\storelabel{node1}{5.7}\getlabel{node1}};
    \node [darkstyle, rectangle] (node2) at (4,2) {\storelabel{node2}{9000.1}\getlabel{node2}};

    % What to write here to change the color of (node2) to blue?
    % A workaround (note the "rectangle" in the options):
    \node [darkstyle, rectangle, fill=blue!30] at (node2) {\getlabel{node2}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: nodes with text]

---

An answer 5 years late, because the others completely dismiss the "after creation" part of the original request.  I mind you that this one also does not re-color an already-drawn node, therefore has drawbacks, and will not be applicable to everyone.  However, the workaround offered here at least does something after creation, as requested.

I would say that this question, even after this one, still needs an answer.