# Is there a nag package for TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nag

It turns out that I've been using several deprecated commands, such as [`\tikzstyle`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles) and [`right of`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz). Is there any way to have TikZ or pdfLaTeX warn in those cases, such as `nag` does?

Comment: `right of` is deprecated?

Comment: I learnt that yesterday. See [Difference between “right of=” and “right=of” in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing an example that uses `\tikzstyle` by percusse at [tikzstyle default node text with fill color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48918/tikzstyle-default-node-text-with-fill-color) I show below how you can redefine the deprecated command to place a warning in the log or alternately, in the console and log.  In this MWE, I have the redefinition in the file itself.  But if you're like me, you have your own style file of oft-used macros that `\usepackage{mycommands}` in just about everything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% PUT THIS IN YOUR OWN STYLE FILE
\let\svtikzstyle\tikzstyle
% LOG FILE ONLY:
%\def\tikzstyle{\wlog{WARNING: tikzstyle is used}\svtikzstyle}
% CONSOLE AND LOG FILE:
\def\tikzstyle{\typeout{WARNING: tikzstyle is used}\svtikzstyle}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% borrowed example from answer by percusse
\tikzstyle{stuff_nofill}=[rectangle,draw,font={A}]
\tikzstyle{stuff_fill}=[rectangle,draw,fill=black!20,minimum
size=1.4em,label={center:A}]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,1) [stuff_nofill] {};
 \node at (0,0) [stuff_fill] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey I was young and I needed money ! :P

Comment: @percusse I can anonymize the example, if it will help you sleep at night ;^S  p.s.  Anyhow, look at me.  I'm still using 1980's vintage jove editor.