# Matching the text background color in tikz with the background color of a presentation slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-shape

I created a polygon using tikz package.  I need to change the background color for my text to match with the background color of the slide. I'm attaching the photo.[image]

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.4]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=1pt,
                    inner sep=0pt]
\draw  node (1) [label=$v_{1,1}$] {}
-- ++(330:2.0cm) node [](2) [] {}
-- ++(270:2.0cm) node (3)
[] {}-- ++(210:2.0cm) node (4)
[] {}-- ++(150:2.0cm) node (5)
[] {}-- ++(90:2.0cm) node (6)
[] {}-- ++(30:2.0cm) node (1)
{};
\path [](1) edge (2);
\path [](2) edge (3);
\path [dashed](3) edge (4);
\path (4) edge (5);
\path (5) edge (6);
\path [](6) edge (1);

\draw (4) node[below,xshift=0mm,draw=white]{Layer 1};
\draw (1) node[below,yshift=-5mm,draw=white]{$K_n$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{$K_n \square P_3$} 
\label{3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please provide compilable MWE.    Answer by @ignasi http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48918/tikzstyle-default-node-text-with-fill-color can give a clue.

Comment: Why not trying to remove `draw=white` from the draw calls of the specific nodes?

Comment: I tried removing that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The background colour can be used under the name `bg`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=orange!50!white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.4]
\usebeamercolor{background canvas}
\tikzset{every node/.style={draw,minimum size=1pt,
                    inner sep=0pt}}
\draw  node (1) [label=$v_{1,1}$] {}
-- ++(330:2.0cm) node [](2) [] {}
-- ++(270:2.0cm) node (3)
[] {}-- ++(210:2.0cm) node (4)
[] {}-- ++(150:2.0cm) node (5)
[] {}-- ++(90:2.0cm) node (6)
[] {}-- ++(30:2.0cm) node (1)
{};
\path [](1) edge (2);
\path [](2) edge (3);
\path [dashed](3) edge (4);
\path (4) edge (5);
\path (5) edge (6);
\path [](6) edge (1);

\draw (4) node[below,xshift=0mm,draw=bg]{Layer 1};
\draw (1) node[below,yshift=-5mm,draw=bg]{$K_n$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Better than filling these nodes with a solid color which matches the background color, is not to fill the nodes. This way, if the background color changes, the code is still correct.

To do so you only have to remove the `fill=white` and `draw=white` options for those nodes. This way, no filling nor drawing takes place.

To have little dots at the vertices of hexagon, you can use `every node/.style` in a scope. Also, do not use `\draw` for the hexagon, but `\path`, since the edges are drawn later.

This is my suggested code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=orange!50!white}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,minimum size=2pt,
             inner sep=0pt, fill}]
  \path  node (1) [label=$v_{1,1}$] {}
  -- ++(330:2.0cm) node [](2) [] {}
  -- ++(270:2.0cm) node (3)
  [] {}-- ++(210:2.0cm) node (4)
  [] {}-- ++(150:2.0cm) node (5)
  [] {}-- ++(90:2.0cm) node (6)
  [] {}-- ++(30:2.0cm) node (1)
  {};
\end{scope}

\path [](1) edge (2);
\path [](2) edge (3);
\path [dashed] (3) edge (4);
\path (4) edge (5);
\path (5) edge (6);
\path [](6) edge (1);
\draw (4) node[below,xshift=0mm,]{Layer 1};
\draw (1) node[below,yshift=-5mm]{$K_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

**Update**. Not related with your question but leveraging the opportunity, your code can be refactorized to use a loop and custom styles, to make it shorter and (imho) more readable:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=orange!50!white}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{
  smalldot/.style={circle,minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt, fill}
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
  \foreach \angle [count=\n from 1] in {30, 90, ..., 330}
      \node[smalldot] (\n) at (\angle:2cm) {};
  \draw (6) -- (1) -- (2) -- (3) -- (4) -- (5);
  \draw [dashed] (5) -- (6);
  \node[above] at (2) {$v_{1,1}$};
  \node[below] at (5) {Layer 1};
  \node at (0,0) {$K_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```